(Lazily) Filling in values into dask array takes increasing amount of time
I have some (~1000) smaller arrays and one big array.
The small arrays all have identical size, around 4000x4000.
The big array is roughly 1e5x1e5 in size, and is created using dask.array.zeros, with a chunk size on the order of the small arrays.
I need to combine all small arrays into the big array.
This is done by summing the small arrays to a properly sized indexed region of the big array.
The indexed regions do not align with chunk boundaries.
I simply loop over the small arrays and perform the index-and-add operation for each of them.
The first few iterations are done fast enough. However, very quickly the process grinds to a halt as the iteration time increases quadratically. For practical use-cases, the loop never comes close to finishing.
Note that this is before any real data moving takes place, since these additions are lazy. The small arrays are lazy-loaded from disk and the big array is a lazy zeros.
The following code snippet provides a minimal reproduction of the problem. I re-use the same small array here, but that doesn't affect the behaviour.
import dask.array
import time
import numpy as np

bgsize = 2**18 # big array size
chsize = 2**13 # chunk size
N = 4096 # small array size

da = dask.array.zeros((bgsize, bgsize), chunks=(chsize, chsize), dtype="float16")
arr = dask.array.random.random((N, N))


t0 = time.time()
for i in range(2000):
    tprev = time.time()
    ip0 = np.random.randint(0, bgsize-N)
    ip1 = np.random.randint(0, bgsize-N)
    da[slice(ip0, ip0+N), slice(ip1, ip1+N)] += arr
    t = time.time()
    print(i, "done", t - tprev, t - t0)

What is causing this slowdown, and how can I better approach this problem?
The starting condition is having one Zarr array on disk that contains all small arrays. The Zarr array is higher-dimensional. The end goal is to write to disk (as quickly as possible) the big array that contains contributions from all (potentially overlapping) small arrays. Essentially the on-disk N-dimensional data must be converted to on-disk 2-dimensional data, but the dimensions cannot be simply stacked as the small arrays are arbitrarily offset w.r.t. each other.
Writing to disk each individual small array in each loop iteration is also not suitable, since the data must be summed. This would then require first reading the existing data in the target area from disk.

If you look at the graph of the array, for example len(da.dask.layers), you will see that in each iteration, the lazy graph gets longer and longer. Unfortunately, the graph building process is not particularly optimized to so many steps; indeed, we in the awkward project have noticed some N^2 scaling similar to what you demonstrate.
So, the question is: what is the real workflow that you are trying to accomplish? Having thousands of layers in your graph is not typical, but having thousands of tasks per layer can be OK.

Thank you for your reply! I checked the layers, and indeed: Every iteration, one layer gets added. I have edited my question to add a brief description of the task at hand (last paragraph). I could create an empty Zarr "scaffold" on disk before starting the loop and fill in the values immediately in each iteration. However, if I want to then parallelize the loop I'll have to manually prevent data corruption when two small arrays have data that belongs to the same big-array-chunk.

da.to_zarr and xarray know about this problem and put a lock around writes to allow parallel processing without races

I see, I am indeed using xarray with dask-backed data. I actually discovered another issue with that approach, which I appended to my post at the end. It would require a disk read before every write.

This is now probably a different question altogether -  maybe you can pose it anew. You can probably do something with repartition and aggregate; if you tag xarray and zarr you will get more notice.
